# auto generate dependency xml for jars

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

i am newbie at maven and i have a standalone java project. there are many jars under lib folder. i would like to convert my java project to maven so i put these jars under local repo folder and defined this folder at pom.xml file. but i need to define dependencies for all these jar files. i don't know their groupId, artifactId and version. some of them i could find these params from web but there are many 3rd party jars. how can i find out these params?

and also i wonder if there is a tool which will take lib folder as parameter and will generate dependencies xml for all jars under that folder?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I once had a drive with hundreds of artifacts and tried to match them to MavenCentral artifacts. It is difficult. Steps I took:

1. Find out which repositories are relevant for you. MavenCentral definitely, but maybe others as well. Gather the URLs.
2. Compute the SHA1 values for all your lib artifacts and look them up in the Maven Repositories. All your matches are fine, non-matches can have two reasons: Either the artifacts are really not present in the repositories, or they are slightly different: The same artifact with the same version number is sometimes published with and without included metadata, which sabotages your SHA1.
3. The non-matches can now be scanned for pom.xml files, which allow you to make further matches.
4. For the remaining artifacts, you can often derive artifactId and version from the file name.

The rest is manual work.

Comment: Supplemental hint: Check if inside the jar files you can find `META-INF/maven/` If it is the case this artifact has been build by Maven and in deeper levels you can find a pom file which contains the groupId/artifactId/version information (but also check sha1 sum to be sure it has not been modified)..